# ElasticSearch - Get extra field in aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get extra field with aggregation. Below is the query
GET /iacmpi/_search?_source=false

```
{    
  "query": {        
        "match": {            
            "Document_Type": "INVOICEDoc"
        }
    },
  "aggs": {
    "GroupByCDMInvoiceID": {       
        "terms":{ "field" : "INVOICE_ID" },
        "aggs":{
            "LatestVersion":{
                "max":{
                "field":"DocVersion"
                }
        }        
        }
  }
}
}
```

So at the level of INVOICE_ID field aggregation, i need to fetch one more field 'NAME'. I dont want that in query part as it will show me all hits and i have to traverse the hits and get a match.

Is it possible?

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: how did you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think [top hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) is what you're looking for.